# Import latitude and longitude from XML to Location field for GMap, for Views display

Tags: views, 6, migrations, location, google-maps

From my XML data which I have imported into nodes, I have CCK fields for Latitude and Longitude. I want to import those values into Node Location so that I can have two Gmap integrations:

- Show a GMap on each node to show where it is located
- Show all matched locations on a Views page with an exposed form

Is there something I have to do with mapping the fields correctly inside of Migrate, and if so, how would I define the Location fields as destination fields? I also found [this](http://drupal.org/node/943178) on Migrate Extras that seems to have integrated it with Location, but that was for D7.

Then, how do I integrate the GMap with my Views page and get items to filter correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was I just made two CCK fields for latitude and longitude. I used the function gmap_simple_map to create a map in my nodes, code placed in the node tempalte file.

Then, in Views, I made a block attachment that was a GMap and chose those CCK fields (which must be defined under fields) as my latitude and longitude.